# Command Line Dynamic name change?

Tags: dynamic, command-line, file-rename

Want to change "file1, file2, file3" to "file1abc, file2abc, file3abc".  But file1, file2, file3 might be named something different tomorrow or the next day.  So I want to do this dynamically, as in "change * to *abc".  But I can't figure it out.  I've tried using REN along with the ?, *, ., c, etc., and can't get it to do this.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What OS and shell are you using?

Comment: Win7, not sure of the shell

Answer (score 0):

The following works on my side with files named `file`, `file2`, etc.

`rename * *abc`

This should append `abc` at the end of the file names.

Comment: Still can't get it (sayd wrong syntax).  What I'm actually trying to do is prepend a date onto the file name, so I should've said file1.txt to abcfile1.txt.  I appologize.  I have the date worked out.  But I can't get it to just prepend it before the whole file name.  I can get it to overwrite up to the .txt.  But I can't get it to just prepend it.  Does that make sense?